# Python multiprocessing functions

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing, python-multithreading, python-multiprocessing

Thanks for taking the time to check this out.

I'm making a line following robot and I've gotten stuck!
I've got 2 sensors and I've written a function to read them that returns integers. I need to run 2 functions at the same time, one for each sensor...

Essentially, there's three things going on.

- `Read1()` reads the left sensor and constantly updates the variable (`while loop`)
- `Read6()` read the right sensor and constantly updates the variable (`while loop`)
- `Main()` takes the two variables and sets motor speeds accordingly.

I need `Read1()` and `Read6()` to break out into their own threads so `Main()` doesn't get blocked waiting for them.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is a psedue code which will help you understand how to implement this using multithreading

```
import threading

thread1 = Read1()
thread2 = Read1()
thread1.start() # This actually causes the thread to run
thread2.start()
thread1.join()  # This waits until the thread has completed
thread2.join()  
# At this point, both threads have completed
Main (thread1.total, threat2.total)
```

Just NOTE: For actual parallelization in Python, you should use the [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html) module to fork multiple processes that execute in parallel (due to the global interpreter lock, Python threads provide interleaving but are in fact executed serially, not in parallel, and are only useful when interleaving I/O operations).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! Thread 1 starts but thread 2 doesn't. Really confused! if the function returns, the thread ends and it refuses to start again so I've made the function not return anything to get around that and now I can't start the second thread. Frustrating! Haha